# Cannot set default terminal to PowerShell 6.0

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, powershell-v6.0

I am trying to set the default terminal in vscode to PowerShell 6.0. However, after restarting vscode, the following message appears and a terminal is not started.

```
ERROR  e.executable.toLowerCase is not a function
```

Here is the user settings override code I have tried using. NOTE: backslash path separators must be escaped.

```
vscode 1.18.1
PSVersion 6.0.0-rc
"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6.0.0-rc\pwsh.exe"

{
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": {
        "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\6.0.0-rc\\pwsh.exe"
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know whether it is supported yet?

Comment: I did not know there was a support problem. The shell is just an executable: cmd.exe, powershell.exe, bash.exe, etc...

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - There is not a "supported" problem. I was using the wrong item to set it. See answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"terminal.integrated.env.windows"` is not the correct property to use.

This works.

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\6.0.0-rc\\pwsh.exe"
}
```

This also works.

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows":
        "C:/Program Files/PowerShell/6.0.0-rc/pwsh.exe"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of 8/26/2019, the path is:

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:/Program Files/PowerShell/6/pwsh.exe"
}
```